# Npm requests stopped by home router

Tags: http, npm, router

Good day.

My machine runs on windows 7 32 bit. I've installed Node.jS via installer from nodejs.org.

When i try to do anything with NPM http request involved, it just stalls. No errors, just continues on and on forever.
With try and error I came to conclusion it is the fault of my home router. I tried setting up DMZ, port forwarding on :80 but nothing helps. Maybe the port is wrong, but i can't find which one to forward.

I don't use proxy and have dynamic ip.

this is how it goes:

```
C:\Users\By-the-ocean\Desktop\delme>npm install -ddd express
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '-ddd',
npm verb cli   'express' ]
npm info using npm@2.10.1
npm info using node@v0.12.4
npm verb install initial load of C:\Users\By-the-ocean\Desktop\delme\package.json
npm verb readDependencies loading dependencies from C:\Users\By-the-ocean\Desktop\delme\package.json
npm sill cache add args [ 'express', null ]
npm verb cache add spec express
npm sill cache add parsed spec { raw: 'express',
npm sill cache add   scope: null,
npm sill cache add   name: 'express',
npm sill cache add   rawSpec: '',
npm sill cache add   spec: '*',
npm sill cache add   type: 'range' }
npm sill addNamed express@*
npm verb addNamed "*" is a valid semver range for express
npm sill addNameRange { name: 'express', range: '*', hasData: false }
npm sill mapToRegistry name express
npm sill mapToRegistry using default registry
npm sill mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm sill mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm verb addNameRange registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/express not in flight;
 fetching
npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 09:18:50
npm verb request id 50d2de54ad349278
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
/
```

A bit more details:
I'm on plain windows laptop connected to internet via router. 
The request comes from the same machine to NPM servers (both http and https versions have been tried)
There is no way for me to connect without router directly via cabel.
Windows firewall has been turned off completely. no firewall on router either.

Comment: give us more details please, are you making the request on the same machine? because DMZ only makes sense if you make requests from a separate machine to you local one

Comment: I confess i don't know what DMZ do, it was on option to a similar problem ot there.
My request comes from the same machine.